# Flashplayer embedding, classid vs type="application/x-shockwave-flash"

Tags: flash, embed, shockwave, clsid

Which is the better way out of the two to embed a flash player?

```
<object id="flashplayer" width="800" height="600" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
```

or

```
<object id="flashplayer" width="800" height="600" data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Are these the same essentially, or is one more efficient than the other

Answer (score 0):

```
<object id="flashplayer" width="800" height="600" data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

needs to be your best choice as it uses html code to define object type.

Comment: Have any particular reason for this?